# Issue with File IO in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

My program is supposed to write and save credit and debit like a "bank account" in a sense. My issue is my program is only saving the last entered line to the text file. I need it to save every instance to the file of when the user enters an input to the text box. Here is my code

```
Public Class Form1
Dim tbDollar As String
Dim tbMemo As String
Dim fName As String
Dim creditAmount As String
Dim debitAMount As String
Dim Balance As Double
Dim action As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Text = "Mike Smith's Bank Account"
    Call LoadData()
    Call MainMenu()
End Sub

Private Sub Cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Cb1.SelectedIndexChanged
    action = Cb1.SelectedIndex
    If action = 0 Then
        Call SetUpCredit()
    ElseIf action = 1 Then
        Call SetUpDebit()
    ElseIf action = 2 Then
        Call ShowTransactions()
    ElseIf action = 3 Then
        Call ShowBalance()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btConfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btConfirm.Click
    If action = 0 Then
        Call ProcessCredit()
        Balance = Balance + Convert.ToDouble(tbDollar)
    ElseIf action = 1 Then
        Call ProcessDebit()
        Balance = Balance - Convert.ToDouble(tbDollar)
    End If
    Cb1.SelectedIndex = -1
    Tb1.Text = ""
    Tb2.Text = ""
    Lb4.Text = Convert.ToString(Balance)
    Lb1.Visible = False
    Lb2.Visible = False
    Tb1.Visible = False
    Tb2.Visible = False
    ListBox1.Visible = False
    btConfirm.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub MainMenu()
    btConfirm.Visible = False
    Lb1.Visible = False
    Lb2.Visible = False
    Tb1.Visible = False
    Tb2.Visible = False
    ListBox1.Visible = False
    Lb4.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub LoadData()
    Dim FileFound = False
    Do Until FileFound = True
        fName = InputBox("Please enter your file path", "Enter your file path")
        If File.Exists(fName) Then
            FileFound = True
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("File not found!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub SetUpCredit()
    btConfirm.Visible = True
    Lb1.Visible = True
    Lb2.Visible = True
    Tb1.Visible = True
    Tb2.Visible = True
    ListBox1.Visible = False
    Lb4.Visible = False
    Lb1.Text = "Enter Credit Amount"
    Lb2.Text = "Enter a Memo"
End Sub

Private Sub SetUpDebit()
    btConfirm.Visible = True
    Lb1.Visible = True
    Lb2.Visible = True
    Tb1.Visible = True
    Tb2.Visible = True
    ListBox1.Visible = False
    Lb4.Visible = False
    Lb1.Text = "Enter Debit Amount"
    Lb2.Text = "Enter a Memo"
End Sub

Private Sub ShowTransactions()
    btConfirm.Visible = False
    Lb1.Visible = False
    Lb2.Visible = False
    Tb1.Visible = False
    Tb2.Visible = False
    ListBox1.Visible = True
    Lb4.Visible = False
    Dim SRObject As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fName)
    Dim ftext As String = SRObject.ReadToEnd()
    ListBox1.Items.Add(ftext)
    SRObject.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ShowBalance()
    btConfirm.Visible = False
    Lb1.Visible = False
    Lb2.Visible = False
    Tb1.Visible = False
    Tb2.Visible = False
    ListBox1.Visible = False
    Lb4.Visible = True
    Lb4.Text = "$" + Convert.ToString(Balance)
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessCredit()
    tbDollar = Tb1.Text
    tbMemo = Tb2.Text
    Dim SWObject As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fName)
    SWObject.WriteLine("Credit: " + tbDollar + ", " + tbMemo)
    SWObject.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessDebit()
    tbDollar = Tb1.Text
    tbMemo = Tb2.Text
    Dim SWObject As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fName)
    SWObject.WriteLine("Debit: " + tbDollar + ", " + tbMemo)
    SWObject.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Tb1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Tb1.KeyPress
    If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then e.Handled = True
    If e.KeyChar = "," And Tb1.Text.IndexOf(",") = -1 Then e.Handled = False
    If e.KeyChar = Chr(8) Then e.Handled = False
    If e.KeyChar = "." And Tb1.Text.IndexOf(".") = -1 Then e.Handled = False
    If e.KeyChar = Chr(13) Then Tb2.Focus()
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The default mode of a `StreamWriter` is to overwrite the file.  It sounds like you want to *append* to the file instead.  To do that, pass `True` as the second parameter in the constructor:

```
Dim SWObject As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fName, True)
```

You'll need to do this in both your `ProcessCredit()` and `ProcessDebit()` methods.

Comment: I can understand how this works, I see it happening in the file, but in my listbox, it keeps adding whatever the file contained to the user entry. I.E., File contains 0.0, user enters Credit: 5.00, Testing. In the listbox, it adds "0.0 Credit: 5.00, Testing" instead of just "Credit: 5.00, Testing". Any solution to this?

Comment: In your `ShowTransactions()` method, you are reading the entire file into a string variable `ftext`  and then calling `ListBox1.Items.Add(ftext)`, which adds a *single* item to the ListBox.  In this case, the "single item" is the entire file.  If you want to add each line of the file as a separate entry in the ListBox, you'll need to use a loop. Inside the loop call `StreamReader.ReadLine` to read the line and `ListBox1.Items.Add` to add it to the ListBox.  You'll probably also want to call `ListBox1.Items.Clear()` before the loop to make sure the list is cleared before you start adding items.